# Drawing straight line graph with large scale

Tags: calculator, geometry

I was given the equation:

$$y(x) = 10000x + 150000 ,~~ 0 \lt x \lt 60$$

and was asked to draw the graph.

I know that it is a positive straight line intercepting through $150000$, but I don't know how to represent this on a graph as the scale is so large. When I tried to emulate it on my calculator I couldn't see the graph (presumably because its so large).

So how would I show this on a graph?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+10000+x+%2B+150000%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+60%7D

Answer (score 0):

To graph the function, go to the "Window" screen. Set the $y$ limits to $y_{min}=-200,000,y_{max}=200,000$. Also, set the $x$ limits to $x_{min}=0,x_{max}=60$. Then, your graph will appear as a straight line intercepting through $150,000$.

Comment: and what about the condition 0 < x < 60?

Comment: @joe See my edited answer.

Comment: When drawing this graph on paper should I scale it down? if not how would i set up each axis?

Comment: @joe Draw the graph as it appears on the calculator, however, be sure to write the scale, i.e., $y$ ranges from $-200,000$ to $200,000$, and $x$ ranges from $0$ to $60$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you plot this on paper, use 1 cm to represent 5 units along the $x$ axis (this will make a 12 cm $x$ axis) and use 1 cm to represent 50000 units along the $y$ axis (this will make a 15 cm $y$ axis).